# Getting strange error in Unity while creating an inventory system

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

So I wanted to create an inventory system and I have coded and done a few things. However now it is showing an error in the item database code. The error is:

> KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Int32[]]].get_Item (Int32 key) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:150)
>   LitJson.JsonReader.Read ()
>   Rethrow as JsonException: Invalid token '123' in input string
>   LitJson.JsonReader.Read ()
>   LitJson.JsonMapper.ReadValue (LitJson.WrapperFactory factory, LitJson.JsonReader reader)
>   LitJson.JsonMapper.ReadValue (LitJson.WrapperFactory factory, LitJson.JsonReader reader)
>   LitJson.JsonMapper.ReadValue (LitJson.WrapperFactory factory, LitJson.JsonReader reader)
>   LitJson.JsonMapper.ToWrapper (LitJson.WrapperFactory factory, System.String json)
>   LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject (System.String json)
>   ItemDatabase.Start () (at Assets/All/Scripts/ItemDatabase.cs:13)

and it became very annoying since I couldn't figure out how to fix it. My 2 files currently are:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using LitJson;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class ItemDatabase : MonoBehaviour {
    private List<Item> database = new List<Item>();
    private JsonData itemData;

void Start()
{
    itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/Items.json"));
    ConstructItemDatabase();

    Debug.Log(database[1].Slug);
}

void ConstructItemDatabase()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < itemData.Count; i++)
    {
        database.Add(new Item((int)itemData[i]["id"], itemData[i]["title"].ToString(), (int)itemData[i]["value"],
            (int)itemData[i]["stats"]["power"], (int)itemData[i]["stats"]["defence"], (int)itemData[i]["stats"]["vitality"], itemData[i]["description"].ToString(),
            (bool)itemData[i]["stackable"], (int)itemData[i]["rarity"], 
itemData[i]["slug"].ToString()));
        }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int Power { get; set; }
    public int Defence { get; set; }
    public int Vitality { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Stackable { get; set; }
    public int Rarity { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }

public Item(int id, string title, int value, int power, int defence, int vitality, string description, bool stackable, int rarity, string slug)
{
    this.ID = id;
    this.Title = title;
    this.Value = value;
    this.Power = power;
    this.Defence = defence;
    this.Vitality = vitality;
    this.Description = description;
    this.Stackable = stackable;
    this.Rarity = rarity;
    this.Slug = slug;
}

public Item()
{
    this.ID = -1;
    }

}
```

Here the top one is my ItemDatabase.cs file. It has a few spaces and brackets are wrong I know but it is actually all fine. I will post a screenshot with the whole code. Since I am new to using this Code Sample tool.

And here is my Items.json file.

```
[
{
    "id": 0,
    "title": "Wood Pickaxe",
    "value": 6,
    "stats" {
      "power": 1,
      "defence": 0,
      "vitality": 0
    },
    "description": "A basic wood pickaxe.",
    "stackable": false,
    "rarity": 1,
    "slug": "wood_pickaxe"
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Wood Pickaxe Head",
    "value": 543,
    "stats" {
      "power": 1,
      "defence": 0,
      "vitality": 0
        },
        "description": "A piece of a broken wood pickaxe.",
        "stackable": false,
        "rarity": 1,
        "slug": "wood_pickaxe_head"
    }
]
```

I will also post a screenshot of this code. Please help. This is very frustrating and the other posts about this won't help. [Items.json screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj2zq.png) [ItemDatabase.cs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMgol.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your json. The error itself is a little misleading. Every time I've seen it, there was a json syntax issue involved.

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "Wood Pickaxe",
        "value": 6,
        "stats": { // <-- problem was here. missing colon
            "power": 1,
            "defence": 0,
            "vitality": 0
        },
        "description": "A basic wood pickaxe.",
        "stackable": false,
        "rarity": 1,
        "slug": "wood_pickaxe"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Wood Pickaxe Head",
        "value": 543,
        "stats": { // <-- problem was here. missing colon
            "power": 1,
            "defence": 0,
            "vitality": 0
        },
        "description": "A piece of a broken wood pickaxe.",
        "stackable": false,
        "rarity": 1,
        "slug": "wood_pickaxe_head"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Jay Jordan! I never realized that.